# What function(s) should I use to either add or subtract in DAX for power BI depending on the date?

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I want to calculate the Overall mileage at the end of each month of two trucks that I have, I have daily miles driven since 10/1/2021, and the overall mileage of each truck at 1/3/2024.

Naturally, the easiest solution is that if the date is before 1/3/2024, subtract the overall mileage minus the daily miles driven and so on to get the overall mileage for each day. If the date is after 1/3/2024, add the miles driven plus the overall mileage of the day before and there you get the overall mileage.

I want to figure this out in DAX for PowerBI.

```
OverallMileage = 
VAR LatestDate = MAX('Millaje Gruas'[Date])
VAR InitialOverallMileage = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('LeyendaMillajeGruas'[OverallMileage]),
        ALL('LeyendaMillajeGruas'),
        'LeyendaMillajeGruas'[Date] = LatestDate
    )
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        'Millaje Gruas'[Date] <= LatestDate, 
            InitialOverallMileage - SUM('Millaje Gruas'[DailyMiles]),
        'Millaje Gruas'[Date] > LatestDate, 
            InitialOverallMileage + SUM('Millaje Gruas'[DailyMiles])
    ),
    ALL('Millaje Gruas'[TruckLicensePlate], 'Millaje Gruas'[Date])
)
```

I tried this but I got nowhere. I don't think I'm factoring in each truck and the specific overall mileages for it.

Comment: Please supply sample data and expected output